# AnchorEl for Popper in functional component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

How can i use `AnchorEl` for popover in functional component where **this** is not available. In component that extends `React.Component` i could use `buttonRef={node => { this.anchorEl = node;}}` on button and then in popper just set `anchorEl={this.anchorEl}`. But now I wanted to switch my Component to use Hooks and have this problem with `AnchorEl`. Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `useRef()` hook, see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref.

Create the reference at the top of the function,

```
let buttonEl=React.useRef(null);
```

Assign it,

```
... buttonRef={buttonEl} ...
```

Use it,

```
... anchorEl={buttonEl} ...
```